# Can not fetch store data from table layout in extjs 4

Tags: extjs4

I am trying to fetch data from store.and i want to use it on my table layout in an extjs panel but always get an empty string though the data is printed in the console. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

```
<code>
        Ext.onReady(function(){ 
        Ext.define('Account', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
                    'id',
                    'name',
                    'nooflicenses'
                ]
                        });
                var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                    model: 'Account',
                    autoSync: true,
                    proxy: {
                            type: 'ajax',
                            api: {
                                   read: "accounts"
                                 },
                         reader: {
                                   type: 'json', 
                                   root: 'Account',
                                   successProperty: 'success',
                                   messageProperty: 'message',
                                   totalProperty: 'results',
                                   idProperty: 'id'
                                 },
                      listeners: {
                                  exception: function(proxy, type, action, o, result, records) {
                                 if (type = 'remote') {
                                    Ext.Msg.alert("Could not ");
                                      } else if (type = 'response') {
                                        Ext.Msg.alert("Could not " + action, "Server's response could not be decoded");
                                        } else {
                                        Ext.Msg.alert("Store sync failed", "Unknown error");}
                                                }
                                 }//end of listeners
                             }//end of proxy
                        }); 
                            store.load();
                                               store.on('load', function(store, records) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                                 console.log(store.data.items[0].data['name']); //data printed successfully here
                                 console.log(store.getProxy().getReader().rawData);
                                 console.log(store);
                                };
                            });


            function syncStore(rowEditing, changes, r, rowIndex) {
                store.save();
            }

            var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
            clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
            autoCancel: false,
            saveText: 'Save',
            listeners: {
                        afteredit: syncStore
                       }
            });

            var grid = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Table Layout',
            width: 500,
            height:'30%',
            store: store,
            layout: {
                type: 'table',
                // The total column count must be specified here
                columns: 2,
                tableAttrs: {
                style: {
                    width: '100%',
                    height:'100%'
                }
                },
                tdAttrs: {
                style: {
                     height:'10%'
                }
                }

            },
            defaults: {
                // applied to each contained panel
                bodyStyle:'border:0px;',
                xtype:'displayfield',
                labelWidth: 120
            },
            items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'My Field1',
                name :'nooflicenses',
                value: store //How to get the data here
                //bodyStyle:'background-color:red;'
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'My Field',
                name:'name',
                value:'name'
            }],
            renderTo: document.getElementById("grid1")
        });
    });

</code>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ext.grid.Panel control is totally configurable so it allows to hide different parts of the grid. In our case the way to hide a headers is adding property: hideHeaders:

Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel", {
    hideHeaders: true,
    columns: [ ... ],
    ... other options ...
});

If you still would like to adopt another solution, the more complex solution I have think about is the use of XTemplate for building table dynamically. (http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate). In this approach you write the template describing how the table will be built.

Otherwise, I still recommend you to deal with the former solution rather than the latter one. The latter approach opposes the basic idea of Sencha ExtJS: use ExtJS library's widgets, customize them in the most flexible way and then automate them by creating store and model.

Answer (score 1):

The most "native" way to show data is by use Ext.grid.Panel.

Example:

Ext.application({
    name: 'LearnExample',

```
launch: function() {
    //Create Store
    Ext.create ('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'example1',
        fields: ['name','email'],
        autoLoad: true,
        data: [
            {name: 'Ed',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
            {name: 'Tommy', email: 'tommy@sencha.com'}
        ]
    });

    Ext.create ('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'example1', 
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('example1'),
        columns: [
            {header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', flex: 1},
            {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1}
        ],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
}
```

});

The grid can be configured in the way it mostly customized for user's needs.

If you have a specific reason why to use Ext.panel.Panel with a table layout, you can use XTemplate, but it more complicate to bind the data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Our requirement is to show the data without the table header so we tried with a panel with 2*2 layout style. Please let us know if there is a better way